# Duplicate and replace a pattern in a text file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Let’s consider an input text file like this:

```
some text …
% BEGIN
blabla
foo bar
blabla
blabla
% END
some text …
```

and a `foobar.txt` file like this:

```
2 3
8 9 
1 2
```

what is the simplest way using `sed` (maybe `awk` ?) to obtain this output text file:

```
some text …
% BEGIN
blabla
2 3
blabla
blabla
% END
% BEGIN
blabla
8 9
blabla
blabla
% END
% BEGIN
blabla
1 2
blabla
blabla
% END
some text …
```

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73969/how-can-i-use-sed-or-awk-to-replace-placeholders-in-a-template-file-with-variabl#74132

Comment: What happened to foo bar?

Comment: So, the input text file contains only one `%BEGIN...%END` block, and that block must be duplicated as many times as `foobar.txt` has values (with the replacement of `foo bar` changing for each copy)? And the text outside that `%BEGIN...%END` block must be left as-is?

Comment: @ilkkachu My understanding exactly the same. Looks like homework :), but it is interesting.

Comment: No homework ;-) Just a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex **bash** + **sed** solution:

***foobar_replacer.sh*** script:

```
#!/bin/bash
head -n1 "$2"  # print the first line

while read -r line
do
    sed '1d;$d;{s/^foo bar$/'"$line"'/g}' "$2"        
done < "$1"

tail -n1 "$2" # print the last line
```

***Usage***:

```
bash foobar_replacer.sh foobar.txt input.txt
```

The output:

```
some text …
% BEGIN
blabla
2 3
blabla
blabla
% END
% BEGIN
blabla
8 9
blabla
blabla
% END
% BEGIN
blabla
1 2
blabla
blabla
% END
some text …
```

---

***sed*** command details:

`1d;$d;` - delete the first and the last line from `input.txt`

`s/^foo bar$/'"$line"'/g` - substitute the line containing `foo bar` with next item `$line` from `foobar.txt`

Comment: @Jean-Pierre Really? :) Are you tested it? Try add in the input file couple lines, like: first line `one`, second line `two`, etc. After `some text` line. I see without running this script, that it is not fulfil your task.

Comment: It does not contain `BEGIN ... END` block location checking. Though it should contain it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure awk way to do it, using `getline`:

```
awk '
  /% BEGIN/ {
    s = 1;
  }

  s == 1 {
    b = b == "" ? $0 : b ORS $0
  }

  /% END/ {
    while ((getline repl < "foobar.txt") > 0) {
      tmp = b;
      sub(/foo bar/, repl, tmp);
      print tmp;
    }
    b = "";
    s = 0;
    next;
  }

  s == 0 {
    print;
  }' input
```

With GNU awk, you can make the substitution without a temporary - using `gensub`:

```
gawk '
  /% BEGIN/ {
    s = 1;
  }

  s == 1 {
    b = b == "" ? $0 : b ORS $0
  }

  /% END/ {
    while ((getline repl < "foobar.txt") > 0) {
      print gensub(/foo bar/, repl, 1, b);
    }
    b = "";
    s = 0;
    next;
  }

  s == 0 {
    print;
  }' input
```

Testing:

```
$ gawk '
>   /% BEGIN/ {s = 1;}
>   s == 1 {b = b == "" ? $0 : b ORS $0}
>   /% END/ {while ((getline repl < "foobar.txt") > 0) {print gensub(/foo bar/, repl, 1, b);} s = 0; next;}
>   s == 0 {print}' input
some text …
% BEGIN
blabla
2 3
blabla
blabla
% END
% BEGIN
blabla
8 9 
blabla
blabla
% END
% BEGIN
blabla
1 2
blabla
blabla
% END
some text …
```

Comment: Good solution, I have analyzed it for awk learning. `b = "";` in the `/% END/` section not needed. I am about pure awk script. Because `b` variable doesn't used anymore, after BEGIN to END block have passed. Right? Have removed it, and script work as expected. Or there is a reason to do this?

Comment: @MiniMax yes you're correct - in fact I didn't include that originally, then added it as a kind of "best practice" thing (to make the solution extensible to the case of more than a single `% BEGIN` . . . `% END` block)

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -nMFatal=open -e '$l = $_;
   @ARGV and open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0];
   print +(/^%\hBEGIN/ ? $a=0 : $a++) == 1 ? $l : $_ while <$fh>;
' foobar.txt input.txt
```

---

Working

- For every line read from the foobar.txt file, we `open` a `lexical` filehandle `$fh` to the file input.txt. The reason it has to be lexical is because it closes by itself when the next line of input from foobar.txt is read in.
- We initialize the counter `$a` when we see the `% BEGIN` line in input.txt. And 1 line after this, we replace the line in input.txt with the line from foobar.txt.
- Order of arguments is: foobar.txt and then input.txt.
- We include the pragma Fatal.pm which handles errors in opening files automatically.

Results

```
some text --
% BEGIN
blabla
2 3
blabla
blabla
% END
some text --
some text --
% BEGIN
blabla
8 9
blabla
blabla
% END
some text --
some text --
% BEGIN
blabla
1 2
blabla
blabla
% END
some text --
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while read line; do awk -v f="$line" '{gsub(/foo bar/, f)} 1' input; done <foobar.txt
```

This reads line by line from `foobar.txt`.  For each `line` in `foobar.txt`, the file `input` is read and the `line` from `foobar.txt` is substituted in for each occurrence of `foo bar`.

#### How it works

- `while read line; do`

  This starts a `while`-loop that reads lines from foobar.txt.
- `awk -v f="$line" '{gsub(/foo bar/, f)} 1' input`

  This reads the file `input` and substitutes in `$line` everywhere that `foo bar` occurs.

  In more detail:

  - `-v f="$line"`

    This creates an awk variable `f` whose value is the contents of shell variable `line`.
  - `gsub(/foo bar/, f)`

    For each line that awk reads in, this looks for occurrences of the regex `foo bar` and substitutes in the value of `f`
  - `1`

    This is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.

  The reason for using awk here, rather than sed, is that awk has better handling for capturing the value of shell variables.
- `done <foobar.txt`

  This signals the end of the `while`-loop and tells the loop to use the file `foobar.txt` as its standard input.

#### Multi-line version

For those who like their commands spread out over multiple lines:

```
while read line
do
    awk -v f="$line" '{gsub(/foo bar/, f)} 1' input
done <foobar.txt
```

Comment: Nice solution. I prefer the one with sed but thanks a lot for the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

`bash` script with `sed` using. Usage: `./search_and_replace.sh < input.txt`,
result will be in the new `output.txt` file

```
#!/bin/bash

begin_str="% BEGIN"
end_str="% END"
pattern="foo bar"
write_to_var_flag=0
output_file=output.txt
foobar_file=foobar.txt
begin_to_end_block_var=""

# clean output file if it exist, else create it
> "$output_file"

function read_foobar_file () {
    while read -r line; do
        echo -ne "$begin_to_end_block_var" | sed "s/$pattern/$line/" >> "$output_file"
    done < "$foobar_file"
}

while read -r line; do
    if  [ "$line" == "$begin_str" ]; then
        write_to_var_flag=1
    fi

    if (( $write_to_var_flag )); then
        begin_to_end_block_var+="$line\n"
    else
        echo "$line" >> "$output_file"
    fi

    if [ "$line" == "$end_str" ]; then
        read_foobar_file 
        write_to_var_flag=0
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '
   1{
      :loop
         N
      /\n\.$/!bloop
      s///;h
      N;s/.*\n//
   }

   G
   y/\n_/_\n/
   s/^\([^_]*\)_\(.*_% BEGIN_[^_]*_\)[^_]*/\2\1/
   y/\n_/_\n/
' input.txt foobar.txt
```

---

#### Working

- In this method, the order of arguments is: input.txt then foobar.txt
- Since POSIX `sed` has no idea when one file ends & the next one begins, we either need to add an eof distinguish-er, say, `.`, OR based on the kind of data in the two files to help tell which file we"re in. In our case, I choose to go by the first method.
- We first store the input.txt file in the hold space, the whole of it.
- Then for every line read in from the foobar.txt file, we append the hold space to it and then replace the 2nd line after the `% BEGIN` line in the pattern space with the first line. Note: We have what is a `multiline pattern space` which is `...\n...\n...\n...`